# Get parts of html code as a new string in python

Tags: python, html, regex, search, variables

I was wondering how I could get a value, between some html tags, from some html code using python.

Say I wanted to get the price of a product in an amazon page:

I've got up to:

```
url = raw_input("Enter the url:\n")
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmlsource = sock.read()
sock.close()
```

so now I got the html source as a string but I don't know how to extract the price. I've played around with re.search but can't get the right expression.

say the price is between `<span class="price">£79.98</span>`

What would be the best way to get `var1 = 79.98`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a HTML Parsing Library. It provides better features than using standard regexs, where you can go wrong easily and it is hard to maintain. Python Standard Library comes with `html.parse` in py3k and `HTMLParser` in python2.x series which would help you parse the HTML file and get the values of the tags.

You may also use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library which many have found easy to use.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="price">79.98</span>')
t = soup.find('span', attrs={"class":"price"})
print t.renderContents()
```

Comment: Thanks, any clues on how to use it for that specific example?

Answer (score 2):

Parsing html by regex is nasty, error-prone, and generally evil.

```
import lxml.html

url = raw_input("Enter the url:\n")
root = lxml.html.parse(url).getroot()
res = root.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()') or []

print res
```

returns something like

```
['\xc2\xa379.98', '\xc2\xa389.98', '\xc2\xa399.98']
```

*Now* we are dealing with plain strings and should use regex,

```
import re

def getPrice(s):
    res =  re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', s)
    if res is None:
        return 0.
    else:
        return float(res.group(0))

prices = map(getPrice, res)
print prices
```

results in

```
[79.98, 89.98, 99.98]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to BeautifulSoup, you might try [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). Here's a [comparison of the two from the `lxml` website](http://codespeak.net/lxml/elementsoup.html).